# Table cells to be edited only on double click

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

The table cell is edit with a simple click, I want it to be edit only on double click. Simple click will select the cell.

I'm use this property of `uitable`:

```
set(hTable, 'Data',data,...
    'ColumnEditable', edit,...
```

Comment: I added a minmal example you can work with. Just copy it in a function script.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to set the cell editabiliy to false by default:

```
set(hTable,'ColumnEditable', [false false ...]);   %accordingly your number of columns
```

and introduce a `CellSelectionCallback`:

```
set(hTable,'CellSelectionCallback',@cellSelect);
```

which calls the following function within the same script

```
function cellSelect(src,evt)
getstate = get(src,'ColumnEditable');  %gets status of editability
index = evt.Indices;                   %index of clicked cell
state = [false false ...];             %set all cells to default: not editable
state(index) = ~getstate(index);       %except the clicked one, was it 
                                       %already false before set it true
set(src,'ColumnEditable', state)       %pass property to table
end
```

and also a `CellEditCallback`:

```
set(hTable,'CellEditCallback',@cellEdit);
```

calling

```
function cellEdit(src,~)
state = [false false ...];
set(src,'ColumnEditable', state)
end
```

---

**minimal example**

```
function minimalTable 

h = figure('Position',[600 400 402 100],'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');
defaultData  =  {'insert number...' , 'insert number...'};
uitable(h,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1],...
              'Data', defaultData,... 
              'ColumnName', [],'RowName',[],...
              'ColumnWidth', {200 200},...
              'ColumnEditable', [false false],...
              'ColumnFormat', {'numeric' , 'numeric'},...  
              'CellSelectionCallback',@cellSelect);

end

function cellSelect(src,evt)
getstate = get(src,'ColumnEditable');
index = evt.Indices;
state = [false false];
state(index) = ~getstate(index);
set(src,'ColumnEditable', state)
end

function cellEdit(src,~)
state = [false false];
set(src,'ColumnEditable', state)
end
```

---

As you figured out this is not always working. Because you have the same issues like I had before with popup menus. It's exactly the same problem: `ColumnEditable` is just a row vector and not a matrix. I had to deal with the `ColumnFormat` property, which is also just a row vector. If the double click feature is really important to you, you can consult the following two answers:

[Is it possible to prevent an uitable popup menu from popping up? Or: How to get a callback by clicking a cell, returning the row & column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406767/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-uitable-popup-menu-from-popping-up-or-how-to-get)

[How to deselect cells in uitable / how to disable cell selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634250/how-to-deselect-cells-in-uitable-how-to-disable-cell-selection-highlighting)

The threads basically suggest to create a unique `uitable` for every single row, so that every single row has a unique `ColumnEditable` property. That's the only solution so far.

I'm afraid there is no simple solution. I can't offer you further help, except the complicated workarounds of the other answers. Or just use the simple one above and live with the little drawbacks.

Comment: Iget an error: Error in ==> cellSelect at 5
    state(index) = ~getstate(index); I've 4 columns In my table should I write     "state = [false false false false];" ?

Comment: yes, you have to write it accordingly to your number of columns.

Comment: Sometime it work fine sometime no, cell edit on simple click :(

Comment: can you post your current code please, so I can have look at it? And is the minimal example working for you?

Comment: the only situation it would work, would be right after "selecting". But you actually would click another cell then.

Comment: It work fine with one row, but more it don't work, try with: defaultData  =  [{'insert number...' , 'insert number...'};{'insert number...' , 'insert number...'}];

Comment: yes I understand the issue, I missed it. Read my final answer and the links there. I'm afraid I can't help you more on that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The objective was to delete the selected rows of a table by clicking on the delete button. So I think to add a column with checkbox. I encounter other problems, I created a new issue for it.

Comment: That's the objective? I would have an elegant solution on that, without a checkbox. Do you want to ask exactly that in another question? Then I post it there.

Comment: I am very interested in your solution, I created the question could you look? thank you. The question is: "Add a checkbox column to table with default value to false"

Comment: but that's the checkbox question. Edit it to something like "How to delete a selected row in uitable?"

Answer (score 2):

Although this thread is old but in my opinion still valuable to some users.
I have tested the following with R2010b 32bit.

I have achieved editing only on double click simply by setting

```
set(hTable,'CellSelectionCallback',@tableCellSelectCB,'ColumnEditable',true)
```

and defining its function the following

```
function tableCellSelectCB(~,~)
    try
            h.jtable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    catch
    end
end
```

where `h.jtable` refers to the underlying java object of your uitable.

This way, I can select even single and multiple cells, without going into edit mode. On a double click on a single cells lets me edit its contents.

### Extension to have individual editable rows

I wanted to have checkboxes in the top row and non-editable (not directly at least) data in the rest of the table. You can easily modify the above:

```
function tableCellSelectCB(~,evd)
    if evd.Indices(1) > 1
        try
            h.jtable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
        catch
        end
    end
end
```